# Replace localhost in heroku

Tags: reactjs, heroku

Going to deploy an application on heroku. I have got requests from react-axios that calls to `localhost`. Now I know that when I deploy it to a server, `localhost` refers to server address.

So how do I change these `localhost` to IP assigned by Heroku.

Here is an example of axios call from react

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getMessages").then((response) => {
      this.setState({ res: response.data });
}
```

Comment: Just do `axios.get("/getMessages")`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change:

```
axios.get("http://localhost:5000/getMessages")
```

to:

```
axios.get("/getMessages")
```

Comment: How stupid of me to not think of this simply. Thanks a ton man! Lots of love!

Answer (score 1):

Since you are hosting your app on heroku, and you are calling your API that is on the same domain, you can use `window.location.hostname`

```
axios.get('${window.location.hostname}:5000/getMessages').then((response) => {
      this.setState({ res: response.data });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

axios.get('heroku deploy address/getMessages')

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).